# TFS picks up wrong build to deploy when <Latest> is selected under 'Select an existing Build:'

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, alm

I am using a build definition that makes use of LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml for deploying the builds. In the lab process settings i have selected "Latest" under 'Select an existing build' in the Build tab. Ideally it should always pickup the latest available build to deploy BUT instead it is picking some old build which was created few days back. The only difference in the old build and the recent builds is that it passed successfully when it was created whereas the recent builds have partially succeeded.

What might be the problem and possible solution? Quick reply would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-w

Answer (score 1):

Latest in that drop down means it will pick up the Latest successful build. It is working as designed.

If you want to change the logic you'll have to edit the XAML workflow and possibly write a custom activity.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, can you provide some help on what and how to write that custom activity.

Comment: deployment is getting failed before even reaching the test execution phase. any suggestions?

Comment: @MrHinsh is talking about fixing the tests in your original build, so instead of Partially Succeeded you get Succeeded build results, then the LabDefault build will pick up the Latest build properly.